# MacBook Pro only turns on at specific times after cleaning

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro has been running fine for the past year. Two days ago when I tried to clean my MacBook Pro with a dry cloth, I heard a half chime sound while I was cleaning the keyboard. Since then my MacBook is not turning on during specific time.

I tried to turn it on until 2am (GMT+5) and nothing happened but when I turn it on after 3am (GMT+5) it turns on normally. When I try to turn it on in the afternoon (after returning from job) it doesn't turn on. This sounds really stupid but I have observed it for two days. I don't what has happened or what to make of it.

It charges normally no problem with that. It doesn't turn on even when battery is fully charged.

Answer (score 1):

Has a schedule been set up? Check in Preferences > Energy Saver. Look at the bottom right under Schedule. You didn't do the cleaning with the power on? Did you hit a shortcut key combo? Here is a shortcut discussion with some common ones to check.: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236  [image: screenshot of Energy Saver window]

Comment: No. I had it turned off while cleaning.

Comment: I think I have verified that schedule thing. I'll double check that again.

Comment: I have verified that. No schedule was set.

Comment: I tried to reset SMC. Now it has gone worse. Not turning on at all.